# Return int value from method in Java

Tags: java, android, return-value, setter, instance-variables

I have a task to make a simple restaurant menu app in `Android`. So, the home page consist of `Food` button and `Drink` button. If `Food` button clicked, the food menu page will appear. If `Drink` button clicked, the drink menu page will appear.

`MainActivity.java`:

```
int x = 1;

public int value()
{
    x = 1;
    return x;
}

public void clickFood(View view)
{
    value();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuList.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public int value2()
{
    x = 2;
    return x;
}

public void clickDrink(View view)
{
    value2();
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuList.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

`MenuList.java`:

```
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView );

    int y = 1;

    if(main.x == y)
    {
        // List of food
        fooddrink = new String[]{"Fried Chicken", "Fried Rice"};
    }
    else
    {
        // List of drink
        fooddrink = new String[]{"Ice Tea", "Ice Coffee"};
    }

    ArrayList<String> listFoodDrink = new ArrayList<String>();
    listFoodDrink.addAll( Arrays.asList(fooddrink) );

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_list_row, listFoodDrink);

    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
```

The problem, the output of `ListView` is **always display food menu**, despite I click `Drink` button. I find that this is because `x` value in `MainActivity.java` doesn't return the value, so the `int x` value always = 1.

How am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Onik main is from : MainActivity main = new MainActivity()

Comment: You are calling value() method which returns int value, but you are not storing the returned value any where. If you want to store it in x, you should call value method like "x = value()". Then based on x you can perform your operations.
In android you do not have to do like this. You can directly listen to the click of particular button and assign the task to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
```

You create a new instance of `MainActivity` (not the one you've "come from") where `x = 1`.

Make `x` in `MainActivity`, for example, *static* like

```
static int x = 1;
```

and use it in `MenuList.java` as follows:

```
if(MainActivity.x == y)
{ ...
```

### **But!**

That is NOT how you should go in `Android` taking into consideration its component's [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle) (more on [that](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle)). Once `MainActivity` has been destroyed by the system, `x`, as being static, is always `= 1`, unless another instance of `MainActivity` has changed it.

So, you may use several options, one of which would be to store `x` value somewhere, e.g. in [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). Another one would be to pass the value within `Intent's` [extra](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) as per @VVJ's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have two activities MainActivity and MenuListActivity.In MainActivity there are two buttons Food and Restaurant. You have handle click event for each as follows:

```
foodButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuList.class);
                  intent.putExtra("type",1);//pass 1 for food
                  startActivity(intent);
             }
         });

restaurantButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuList.class);
                  intent.putExtra("type",2);//pass 2 for Restaurant
                  startActivity(intent);
             }
         });
```

Now in your MenuList activity you have to take value of key "type" and based on type value pass appropriate data source to adapter.You can do something like this(in onCreate of MenuList activity):

```
 int type=getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getInt("type");
 i(type==1)
    {
        // List of food
        fooddrink = new String[]{"Fried Chicken", "Fried Rice"};
    }
    else
    {
        // List of drink
        fooddrink = new String[]{"Ice Tea", "Ice Coffee"};
    }

    ArrayList<String> listFoodDrink = new ArrayList<String>();
    listFoodDrink.addAll( Arrays.asList(fooddrink) );

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.menu_list_row, listFoodDrink);

    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
```